# "While .. End While" doesn't work in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

The code below is VBA for Excel. I am using the Visual Basic editor that comes with Excel 2007.

```
Dim counter As Integer
counter = 1
While counter < 20
    counter = counter + 1
end while '<- the compiler is complaining about this statement
```

The code doesn't compile. Above the code I have only declarations. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1f56zs.aspx)   this should work but it doesn't. What has happened?

Comment: Out of the two answers so far (`Do While / Loop` and `While / Wend`) I recommend the `Do While` option for the simple reason that you can break out of this loop if necessary with the `Exit Do` function.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`While` constructs are terminated not with an `End While` but with a `Wend`.

```
While counter < 20
    counter = counter + 1
Wend
```

Note that this information is readily available in the documentation; just press <kbd>F1</kbd>. The [page you link to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1f56zs.aspx) deals with Visual Basic .NET, not VBA. While (no pun intended) there is some degree of overlap in syntax between VBA and VB.NET, one can't just assume that the documentation for the one can be applied directly to the other.

Also in the VBA help file:

> **Tip**   The `Do...Loop` statement provides a more structured and flexible way to perform looping.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I must say it is a bit confusing to have two different languages, three actually, with almost the same name and almost the same statements.

Answer (score 15):

[VBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) is *not* VB/VB.NET

The correct reference to use is [Do..Loop Statement (VBA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278815.aspx). Also see the article [Excel VBA For, Do While, and Do Until](http://www.databison.com/index.php/excel-vba-for-do-while-and-do-until-loop/). One way to write this is:

```
Do While counter < 20
    counter = counter + 1
Loop
```

(But a [For..Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251601.aspx) might be more appropriate here.)

Happy coding.

Comment: +1 I would go `For .. Next`. It also allows an exit `Exit For`

Comment: @Fionnuala, you can also exit a `Do While..Loop` as well using `Exit Do`. I'm not sure if you can exit a `While.. Wend` though.